# How to change move interval in EXTJS calendar?

Tags: extjs, calendar

How to change the move interval in EXTJS calendar (modern toolkit)?

I would like to have a week view and to change value by 30 days.

By default this move interval is set to 7 days. In addition, there is a property `getMoveInterval` that returns units to move and number of units to move `{unit: "d", amount: 7}`. However, there is no such thing as `setMoveInterval`.

In ideal case, I would like to have this config as `{unit: "m", amount: 1}`

I tried to change value in `valuechange` event of week view:

```
valuechange: function (a){
    //some calculations to calculate newDate;
    a.setValue(newDate);
}
```

but then I fall into infinite loop:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

On the other hand, I don't see any other appropriate method to detect changing the displayed date interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do so by overriding the following class for week or month (there are the same functionalities for workweek...):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.overrides.calendar.view.Week', {
    override: 'Ext.calendar.view.Week',

    privates: {
        getMoveInterval: function() {
            var D = Ext.Date;
            return {
                unit: D.DAY,
                amount: 30    // D.DAYS_IN_WEEK
            };
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.overrides.calendar.view.Month', {
    override: 'Ext.calendar.view.Month',

    privates: {
        getMoveInterval: function() {
            return {
                unit: Ext.Date.MONTH,
                amount: 6            // 1
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Because `getMoveInterval` is a private function you have to override it as such.